# YII-1.1.13, GII login not working

Tags: php, yii, gii

I'm unable to login in Yii Gii module.

I'm setting right password in config/main.php.

```
'modules'=>array(
    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'SOME_PASSWORD',
        'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1', '::1'),
    ),
),
```

When I'm passing r=gii its loading the login page but even after entering correct password it's not logging in. It's showing same login page again and again. Even it's not showing any error message.

**I am using mac x and Google Chrome browser **

Comment: Are you accessing the server through 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Joni yes, I am using localhost. This code is running on my machine only

Comment: Did you make sure, that your session directory is writeable? Add a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` on top of `index.php` to find out where it's located. Check the setting for `session.save_path`. Also check your webserver's error log for any warnings.

Comment: Try it in FireFox or some other Browsers..

Comment: @MichaelHärtl I checked the "session.save_pat" its nil(No Value). Its looks like issue with XAMPP. I reverted back to old version of XAMPP and its working fine now. I think this issue is related to XAMPP 1.8.2. Thanks for your reply